# mod_rewrite/htaccess redirect issue! (recursion limit)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create my mod_rewrite file so that basically all of the .php extensions are removed when you view a file.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Now here's the error i get from my apache log when trying a random name:

```
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi.php
[Tue Jan 31 17:26:05 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /aboutasdfoi
```

How do i go about fixing it? Thanks

Comment: Remove the recursion, then you won't hit the limit.

Comment: What are you trying to redirect to?

Comment: Where is the recursion? I'm pretty bad at .htaccess writing so this was generated and partly written!

Comment: Well i  simply want to remove the .php to all files i have so for example about.php, index.php etc.
And then I obviously have the ErrorDocuments relating to each error!
The test for "aboutasdfoi" was just a test as aboutasdfoi.php doesn't exist, so I was hoping it would go to my 404 page!

Comment: EDIT: NOT SOLVED!
Ok I solved the error myself, just found out it's the ( and ) causing it, which i assume is the recursion :) I'll look into it more now!

Comment: Infact removing the ( and ) doesn't work, as if i go to /portfolio it just displays a 404 error.

Comment: @hakre.  That's a dumb suggestion, or putting the nicest face on it -- an ironic one.  It's an infinite loop.  You can't remove this hardstop, just move the error elsewhere!

Comment: Just add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php\.php` to the rule and this will stop the loop.

Answer (score 2):

To hide `.php` extension use this code:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you then can you accept this answer to close this Q&A.

Comment: anubhava, have you tried a test vector `fred?param=1`. Your algo will generate `fred?param=1.php.php.php.php` etc. before barfing on a recursion limit. `%{REQUEST_URI}` _includes_ any get parameters.

Comment: @TerryE wrote: `%{REQUEST_URI} includes any get parameters`. Sorry for being blunt but you are absolutely wrong. Pls read some Apache docs on mod_rewrite before making comments like this. Just fyi: %{REQUEST_URI} contains only the URI and %{QUERY_STRING} actually has all the Get parameters.

Comment: :Oops:  Got to +1 you on that.  My confusion is that the _Environment variable_ `REQUEST_URI` does, but the rewrite variable `%{REQUEST_URI}` doesn't as you can see [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/info?fred=1).  This is just a phpinfo() but I've added a diagnostic `RewriteRule .? - [E=REQ_URI:%{REQUEST_URI}]` to my docroot `.htaccess` file.  Search for "REQUEST_URI" and "REDIRECT_REQ_URI".